# Express error cannot read property status of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm doing a app of a list of products. When I do the conection to the MongoDB database, my console give me an error: `return res.status(200).send()  Cannot find status property of undefined`

I'm researching for the error and I don't find in what the because of the error

My code:

Index.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var port = 3700;

var app = require('./app');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/productos", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, )
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Conectado a la base de datos correctamente");

            app.listen(port, () => {
                console.log("Servidor corriendo correctamente en localhost:3700");
            });
        })
        .catch ((err) => console.log(err));
```

app.js

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// cargar archivo Rutas
var routes = require('./routes/product');

// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Content-Type: image/jpg

// CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    next();
});

// Rutas
app.use('/api', routes);

// exportar
module.exports = app;
```

product.js //Controller

```
var controller = {
    home: function(req, res){
        return res.status(200).send({
            message: "Conectado a la home"
        });
    }
}

module.exports = controller;
```

product.js //Routes

```
    var ProductController = require('../controllers/product');
var express = require('express');

var routes = express.Router();

routes.get('/home', ProductController.home());

module.exports = routes;
```

Thanks for all

Comment: try `routes.get('/home', ProductController.home);`

Comment: Thank you, I solved the issue.